# The sub-menu in nested navigation is not working as expected

Tags: html

I am trying to write a HTML documentation for my team project. When I was trying to create a navigation menu with nested structure, the second degree doesn't show any content. Can I get some suggestion on possible cause of my problem?

```
    <section class="contents">
        <h1 id="contents">Contents</h1>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#problem-statement-and-project-overview">Problem Statement and Project Overview</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#overview"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#background"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#problem"></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#solution"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#use-case">Use Case</a></li>
            <li><a href="#development-timeline">Development Timeline</a></li>
            <li><a href="#technology">Technology </a></li>
            <li><a href="#data-sources">Data Sources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team-capabilities">Team Capabilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#user-interface">User Interface</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```

[image]

Comment: Your a tags empty in your code, why?

Comment: What content do you want to see? You have not specified anything inside the `<a>` tags for the submenu.

Comment: Thanks Problem Solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put some content between your `a` tags

```
<section class="contents">
        <h1 id="contents">Contents</h1>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#problem-statement-and-project-overview">Problem Statement and Project Overview</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#overview">overview</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#background">background</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#problem">problem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#solution">solution</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#use-case">Use Case</a></li>
            <li><a href="#development-timeline">Development Timeline</a></li>
            <li><a href="#technology">Technology </a></li>
            <li><a href="#data-sources">Data Sources</a></li>
            <li><a href="#team-capabilities">Team Capabilities</a></li>
            <li><a href="#user-interface">User Interface</a></li>
        </ul>
    </section>
```